# Symfony2 : How to Force multiple => false in a Collection

Tags: symfony

I try pu a multiplie => false to a manytomany relation but i had this error.

```
Expected an object, but got a collection. Did you forget to pass
```

"multiple=true" to an entity field?

So I find a solution but i have an other error.

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Plop\PlipBundle\Form\{closure}() must be an instance of Plop\PlipBundle\Form\Collection, null given in /var/www/Symfony/src/plop/plipBundle/Form/CampaignSupportType.php line 22
```

And is my code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder->add(
    $builder->create('supports', 'entity', array(
      'class' => 'PlopPlipBundle:Support','multiple' => false,
      'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
         return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
           ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
       }, 'property' => 'name'))
    ->prependNormTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        // transform the collection to its first element
        function (Collection $coll) { return $coll[0]; },
        // transform the element to a collection
        function (MyEntity $entity) { return new ArrayCollection(array($entity)); }
    ))
   );
 }
```

**edit**

With @bernhard answer, I got a new error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Plop\PlipBundle\Form\{closure}() must be an instance of Plop\PlipBundle\Form\Collection, instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given in /var/www/Symfony/src/plop/PlipBundle/Form/CampaignSupportType.php line 22
```

Now is not null given but `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` and Symfony2 wait a `Plop\PlipBundle\Form\Collection`.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your transformation functions to accept `null`, since the field may be empty or unselected.

```
->prependNormTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
    // transform the collection to its first element
    function (Collection $coll = null) {
        return $coll ? $coll[0] : null; 
    },
    // transform the element to a collection
    function (MyEntity $entity = null) {
        return new ArrayCollection($entity ? array($entity) : array());
    }
))
```

Then your code should work just fine.